# Firestore security rules: check for not exists(/collection/document)

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

In firebase firestore security rules, I want to allow a request only if a particular document does not exist. My code is:

```
match /users/{user_id} {
 allow create: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/merchants/$(request.auth.uid));
}
```

I am pretty sure the document does not exist but it does not work.
Both `exists()` and `!exists()` give false somehow, or maybe `!exists()` raises some error.

I have even tried:

```
match /users/{user_id} {
 allow create: if exists(/databases/$(database)/merchants/$(request.auth.uid)) == false;
}
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 10):

Are your rules inside the database block? Cause I had a similar problem and was actually putting the rule bellow the database block, and my rule was using the `$(database)`parameter just like yours

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{user_id} {
            allow create: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/merchants/$(request.auth.uid));
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: This really helped me out - I had a whole bunch of functions using $(database) and they did not work because they were not within the matched scope.